# Sphinx RT index and search in json by value

Tags: database, sphinx

In rt index i have fields - `fields` with `rt_attr_json` attributes.
In this field i have such structure (collection of same blocks):

```
{
  block_name: "a",
  block_type: 1,
  elements: {
     {
       ...
     }
  }
}
```

How I can get all records from sphinx which has `block_type = 1` and `not empty elements` in this block?

I know how this realize if I know a key of block:

```
where fields[0].block_type=1 and fields[0].elements is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I completely understood the question, but the following works nicely in Sphinx 3.1.1:

```
mysql> select * from jt;
+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id   | title | j                           |
+------+-------+-----------------------------+
|    1 |       | {"type":1}                  |
|    2 |       | {"type":1,"elements":[]}    |
|    3 |       | {"type":1,"elements":[123]} |
|    4 |       | {"type":2}                  |
|    5 |       | {"type":2,"elements":[123]} |
+------+-------+-----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from jt where j.type=1 and j.elements is not null;
+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id   | title | j                           |
+------+-------+-----------------------------+
|    2 |       | {"type":1,"elements":[]}    |
|    3 |       | {"type":1,"elements":[123]} |
+------+-------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that any previous versions might behave differently, as NULL handling was fixed to the point of being semi-rewritten in the most recent 3.1.1 release.

Comment: Some problems, because in one field `j` I can have several blocks like this `{"type":1,"elements":[]} `. For examlde, id = `1`, j = `[{"type":1,"elements":[]},{"type":2,"elements":[...]}]`

Comment: And when exactly should the row match?